# Changer the color of f:facet name="header" in primefaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Is there any way that i can use to change the color (css style in general) of a facet header in datatable (primefaces).

```
            <p:dataTable id="iddata" var="test" value="#{test.getDataValue()}"
            styleClass="borderless">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:graphicImage value="../../theme/images/ffolder.png" />
                <h:outputText value="Your data" styleClass="outputTextStyle"></h:outputText>

                    <p:commandButton id="dynaButton2" value="add data" ajax="true"
                    action="#{lpcRecordAddition.formSubmit}"/> 

            </f:facet>

            <p:column>
                <p:panelGrid>

                    ... some code ...
                </p:panelGrid>

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <div style="float: left;">
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="" style="width:160px">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="tezst1" itemLabel="action" />
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="tezst2" itemLabel="test1" />
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="tezst3" itemLabel="test2" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </div>
                </f:facet>

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <div style="float: left;" >
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="" style="width:160px">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="tezst1" itemLabel="sir" />
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="tezst2" itemLabel="test1" />
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="tezst3" itemLabel="test2" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </div>
                </f:facet>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

I would like to change the color of the 2 facet headers which contains the 2 last comboboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Datatable would be rendered as HTML table. So the column header would be `th`

You can achieve this from below CSS

```
.customHeader th{
    background-color: black;
}
```

Specify `styleClass` for the required `p:column`

```
<p:column styleClass = "customHeader ">
...
</p:column>
```

Comment: Actually the solution was simple :


    .borderless thead tr .ui-state-default[role="columnheader"]
{
 background :rgb(50, 69, 76);
}


Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the solution was simple :

```
.borderless thead tr .ui-state-default[role="columnheader"] {
    background :rgb(50, 69, 76);
}
```